# Getting Errors with @ManyToOne in Play using @MappedSuperclass

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I am trying to set up our database in our project. But I get some errors, when I try to use @ManyToOne and@OneToMany on a @MappedSuperclass Entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Person extends Model{
//public abstract class Person {

    // ATTRIBUTES
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(20) not null")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(20) not null")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(20) not null")
    private String password;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(50) not null")
    private String eMail;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(8) not null")
    private String svn;
    private static int staticId = 0;  // Identifier, staticId is unique.
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer not null")
    private int id;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer")
    private int age;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(10)")
    private String telephoneNumber;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "decimal(10,2)")
    private double salary;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean")
    private boolean allowedOvertime;
    //@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<TimeEntryMonth> listTimeEntryMonth;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<Vacation> listVacation;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private List<SickLeave> listSickLeave;
```

One of the classes who extends from Person:

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends Person {

    // ATTRIBUTES
    private String position;
    private Boss boss;
```

And  one of the @OneToMany relations:

```
public class SickLeave extends Model {

    /* ATTRIBUTES */
    @Id
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;
    private int personIdSL;
    private String reason;
```

If I compile my whole Project without the @ManyToOne and @OneToMany, it will work fine. But with the it will lead into som errors:

> Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading
>   annotations for models.SickLeave

I tried to delete the abstract and replaced @MappedSuperclass with @Entity and the project works. So I think that I cant have @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relations on a @MappedSuperclass, But I dont want to refactor my whole project

Is there any (easier) way to handle such issues?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a constructor in your code at all? Im looking at some examples and it looks like you need a constructor...

Comment: Thank you. Yes, Every class has defined their own Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`Person` is not an `Entity`, so you can't use `OneToMany` to it. You will need to make `Person` an `Entity` or point to `Employee`, which seems to make more sense to me.